# Can't import module with typescript alias in storybook for react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, storybook

### What I faced

I'm creating a mobile app with `TypeScript`, `React Native`, and `Storybook`.

A storybook code can import another component something like below without TS Error.

- Button.stories.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/react-native";
import CenterView from "../../../storybook/stories/CenterView";
import { Button } from "@/components/Button/Button";

storiesOf("Componets", module)
  .addDecorator(getStory => <CenterView>{getStory()}</CenterView>)
  .add("button", () => <Button title="Confirm" />);
```

However, there is an error about storybook can not recognize `@/components/Button/Button`

The error is this.

```
Unable to resolve module @/components/Button/Button from /Users/myproject/src/components/Button/Button.stories.tsx: @/components/Button/Button could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
```

### Versions and configurations

This is my `package.json`. Storybook versions are in this.

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 7007",
    "prestorybook": "rnstl",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^5.3.23",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-knobs": "^5.3.25",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.25",
    "@storybook/react-native-server": "^5.3.23",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.7.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native-storybook-loader": "^2.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

- tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "esnext" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
    "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react-native" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "noEmit": true /* Do not emit outputs. */,
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    "isolatedModules": true /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
    "baseUrl": "./" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@/components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@/navigation/*": ["src/navigation/*"]
    },
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    "skipLibCheck": false /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "resolveJsonModule": true /* Allows importing modules with a ‘.json’ extension, which is a common practice in node projects. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

- .storybook/main.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: config => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alise,
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"),
      "@/components": path.resolve(__diraname, "../src/components"),
      "@/navigation": path.resolve(__diraname, "../src/navigation"),
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

- directory structure

```
project-root/
├ .storybook/
├ storybook/
├ src/
   ├ components
   ├ navigation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storybook mentions how to resolve this with typescript https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#typescript-module-resolution

From their docs

```js
// .storybook/main.js

const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve.plugins = [
      ...(config.resolve.plugins || []),
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        extensions: config.resolve.extensions,
      }),
    ];
    return config;
  },
};
```